# How to end an AppleScript Process

Tags: applescript

Basically, what I want to do is have a window open in the top right corner when the script is started, and you can click the button in the dialogue which will end the process.

I have no idea how to do this, because I'm new to AppleScript.
I have tried this:

```
display dialogue "Here is where you can end the process.."
buttons {"End Process"}
copy the result as list to {text_returned, button_pressed}
if button_pressed contains "End Process" then
tell application Spammer
end process
end tell
```

Help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, check out AppleScript-Editor's Preferences. There you should activate the Script-Assistant (Second Tab). Now you can type something (try display...) and with the Escape-Key you get the code-completion list.

Next: CTRL-Click into an AppleScript and it shows you a list of scripts you can insert. Try the menu "Dialogs". This is often very helpful.

Anyway, may be you want something like this:

```
display dialog "Quit Spammer" buttons {"Cancel", "Quit"} default button 2

if the button returned of the result is "Cancel" then

    -- action for 1st button goes here
    return

else

    -- action for 2nd button goes here
    tell application "Spammer" to quit

end if
```

Comment: Awesome! You rock, thank you so much.
The dialog displayed, and it ended the process. 
Thank you so much!

Comment: Oh, wait. There is a problem.
It seems that the rest of the script won't start until I give input.
I want it to be available during the script, not before anything happens.

Comment: Yeah, combine your new knowledge with adayzdon's answer |

Answer (score 1):

Without getting too complicated, you can periodically prompt a user to quit:

```
set counter to 0
set interval to 5

repeat
    delay 1
    set counter to counter + 1
    --insert your code that does things here

    if counter mod interval = 0 then
        if not gave up of (display dialog "Here is where you can end the process.." buttons {"End Process"} default button 1 giving up after 2) then exit repeat
    end if
end repeat
```